# How to add a second object into jsonArray

Tags: java, arrays, json

I am trying to read a excel bulk data and save it into database. While reading the excel file first row data is pushed into json array, while reading second row it is not inserted the data into json. please check the below code.

```
private JsonArray readBulkUsers(String file) throws IOException {
int count = 0;
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
 //Get the workbook instance for XLS file 
   HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(fis);
   //Get first sheet from the workbook
   HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);

   JsonArrayBuilder blist = Json.createArrayBuilder();

   //Iterate through each rows from first sheet
   Iterator<Row> rowIterator = sheet.iterator();
   JsonObjectBuilder userjson = Json.createObjectBuilder();
   while(rowIterator.hasNext()) {
       Row row = rowIterator.next();

       if(row.getRowNum()==0){
          continue; //just skip the rows if row number is 0
      }

       Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();
       while(cellIterator.hasNext()) {                
           Cell cell = cellIterator.next();
           if(count == 0)   {
           userjson.add("email", cell.getStringCellValue());
           } else if(count == 1)    {
                userjson.add("firstname", cell.getStringCellValue());
            } else if(count == 2)   {
                userjson.add("lastname", cell.getStringCellValue());
            } else if(count == 3)   {
                userjson.add("password", cell.getStringCellValue());
            }
           count ++;

       }

    blist.add(userjson.build());
}
   fis.close();
   return blist.build();
}
```

below value i am getting :
[{"email":"test@gmail.com","firstname":"test","lastname":"ppppp","password":"password"},{}]

please help me out to complete this loop.

Comment: You never reset `count` back to zero, and so it will never add more fields to the JSON list after the first one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a new JsonObjectBuilder inside the while

```
   while(rowIterator.hasNext()) 
  {
   count=0;
   Row row = rowIterator.next();

   if(row.getRowNum()==0){
      continue; //just skip the rows if row number is 0
  }
    JsonObjectBuilder userjson = Json.createObjectBuilder();
   Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();
   while(cellIterator.hasNext()) {                
       Cell cell = cellIterator.next();
       if(count == 0)   {
       userjson.add("email", cell.getStringCellValue());
       } else if(count == 1)    {
            userjson.add("firstname", cell.getStringCellValue());
        } else if(count == 2)   {
            userjson.add("lastname", cell.getStringCellValue());
        } else if(count == 3)   {
            userjson.add("password", cell.getStringCellValue());
        }
       count ++;

   }

blist.add(userjson.build());
```

}